# Ring of Polynomials Commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Can $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients $\in k$ where $k$ is a field, ever be a non-commutative ring?

Comment: No, by definition.

Comment: No, it cannot be non-commutative.

Comment: It is commutative.

Comment: Ah, a much better solution to the 15-character problem, @ZhenLin

Comment: In addition to what others have said, one can define a non-commutative polynomial ring by declaring the variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ to be non-commutative.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the free algebra is a polynomial ring. In any case, surely one simply fails to declare the variables commutative, as opposed to declaring them non-commutative?

Comment: Is your question about what said *notation* means, or is it about whether there exist noncommutative generalizations of polynomial rings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is used to denote the ring of polynomials in $n$ indeterminates over $k$ and that is, by definition, commutative.

There is a thing that could be seen as a *non-commutative polynomial ring*: the [free algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) on $n$ symbols $x_1, \dots, x_n$ over $k$. It can be constructed in a way analoguously to an ordinary polynomial ring: elements are finite sums of (non-commutative) monomials of the form $\alpha \vec x$, where $\alpha \in k$ and $\vec x$ is a (finite, possibly empty, repetitions allowed) sequence of elements of the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. I've seen it denoted by $k\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ and by $k\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. (Note that this boils down to exactly is said in the comments: you declare the variables to be non-commuting; or, maybe more accurately formulated, you do not declare them to be commuting.)

Comment: when we say "*...polynomials in n indeterminates over $k$*" do we mean the values that $x_n$ can take come from $k$?

Comment: It is slightly more subtle. Polynomials are not functions, so there is - at least not by definition - no such thing as 'values that the $x_i$ can take on'. Given a $k$-algebra $A$, you can _interpret_ a polynomials in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ as functions from $A^n$ to $A$, so in that context you can say that the $x_i$ can take on values in $A$. And you can apply this to $A=k$, so a polynomial indeed can be interpreted as a function $k^n \to k$.

Comment: That makes sense. So if we study $p = x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$, and select $x = 6$ when  $6 \notin  \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ we can still get something meaningful: $p = 1$?

Comment: I would say $6 = 0 \in {\mathbb Z}_2$ (although formally it is of course that 'the residue class of $6$' = 'the residual class of $0$' ${}\in {\mathbb Z}_2$).

Comment: But, yes, evaluating $x + 1 \in {\mathbb Z}_2[x]$ at $x = 6 (= 0)$ gives $1$.